# How to Import excel files into Overleaf?

Tags: overleaf, mdpi

I have seen docs which explains manually entering data from overleaf source.But it is a cumbersome process if there's more data. If I have excel sheets how can I use it to import into overleaf?

Comment: How is overleaf suppose to read excel? I don't think it does (could be wrong). It might be easier to convert to csv and then use packages like datatool to import the data

Comment: Nothing stops you from uploading Excel spreadsheets to an Overleaf project. But no matter whether you use Overleaf or your own local TeX distribution, LaTeX in general can't read Excel files for typesetting. You'd need to find a package that can (I don't know of any) or convert to some other format as daleif suggests.

Comment: https://ctan.org/pkg/excel2latex

Comment: https://ctan.org/pkg/exceltex